# python selenium find element with attribute containing sometext

Tags: python, selenium

There is a li element which I want to select and it has only this information:

```
<li onclick="show_some_unique_action()"></li>
```

How can I do this in python and selenium? Is it possible to select the li that has an onclick attribute with text containing show_some_unique_action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use below XPath :-

```
//li[@onclick='show_some_unique_action()']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below xpath to locate the element

```
//*/li[contains(concat(' ', @onclick, ' '), ' show_some_unique_action() ')]
```

It will locate the element.